# DYMO Javascript Website Printing using URL for Image Location

Tags: java, xml, dymo

I am working on a project where name tags are printed from a DYMO Labelwriter. I am not having an issue with the printer printing labels. I have successfully printed the labels with correct information from the server. One thing I need help with is printing an image saved on my server. During my research, I found an example on DYMO website where they specify an image location. I have tried this with different URL's from my server and other servers. The tag still prints the correct information, but no image shows up.

Here is the image object portion from the XML file.

```
 <ObjectInfo>\
 <ImageObject>\
         <Name>IMG</Name>\
         <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
         <BackColor Alpha="0" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255" />\
         <LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName>\
         <Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation>\
         <IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored>\
         <IsVariable>False</IsVariable>\
         <ImageLocation>http://...</ImageLocation>\
         <ScaleMode>Uniform</ScaleMode>\
         <BorderWidth>0</BorderWidth>\
         <BorderColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
         <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment>\
         <VerticalAlignment>Center</VerticalAlignment>\
     </ImageObject>\
<Bounds X="3599.732" Y="1359.777" Width="2030.668" Height="1616.223"/>\
</ObjectInfo>\
```

I can upload the whole XML file if needed.

The example from DYMO can be found here: http://developers.dymo.com/tag/xml/.

Comment: _"no image shows up"_ -- what does this mean?  White space? A black square?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm assuming it's a blank square. Everything else prints on the tag where it should go. Nothing is out of place. This could also be because all other elements are aligned with the bounds field.